# How to extract values from an array of arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a variable as follows:

```
var dataset = {
"towns": [
    ["Aladağ", "Adana", [35.4,37.5], [0]],
    ["Ceyhan", "Adana", [35.8,37], [0]],
    ["Feke", "Adana", [35.9,37.8], [0]]
    ]
};
```

The variable has a lot of town data in it. How can I extract the first elements of the third ones from the data efficiently? I,e, what will `...` be below?

```
var myArray = ...
//myArray == [35.4,35.8,35.9] for the given data
```

And what to do if I want to store both values in the array? That is

```
var myArray = ...
//myArray == [[35.4,37.5], [35.8,37], [35.9,37.8]] for the given data
```

I'm very new to Javascript. I hope there's a way without using for loops.

Comment: What's wrong with for-loops?

Comment: where's the connection to json?!

Comment: @Veger Nothing wrong. I'm coming from MATLAB background. That's why I look for non-loop solution I think.

Comment: Loops in JavaScript are not evil :)

Comment: see below, there's a loop free way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083524/how-to-extract-values-from-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript/14083662#14083662

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On newer browsers, you can use `map`, or `forEach` which would avoid using a `for` loop.

```
var myArray = dataset.towns.map(function(town){
  return town[2];
});
// myArray == [[35.4,37.5], [35.8,37], [35.9,37.8]]
```

But for loops are more compatible.

```
var myArray = [];
for(var i = 0, len = dataset.towns.length; i < len; i++){
  myArray.push(dataset.towns[i][2];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Impossible without loops:

```
var myArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dataset.towns.length; i++) {
    myArray.push(dataset.towns[i][2][0]);
}
// at this stage myArray = [35.4, 35.8, 35.9]
```

> And what to do if I want to store both values in the array?

Similar, you just add the entire array, not only the first element:

```
var myArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dataset.towns.length; i++) {
    myArray.push(dataset.towns[i][2]);
}
// at this stage myArray = [[35.4,37.5], [35.8,37], [35.9,37.8]]
```