# How to return element out of array using filter method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets-api

This code returns an array of arrays:

```js
var values = [[1],["a"],,["b"],[""],["c"]];
var noBlankValues = values.filter(function (el) {
  var v = el != null && el != "";
  return v;
});
console.log(noBlankValues);
```

How should I change it to get an array like `[1,"a","b","c"]`?
I tried this but with no luck:

```js
    var values = [[1],["a"],,["b"],[""],["c"]];
    var noBlankValues = values.filter(function (el) {
      var v = el != null && el != "";
      return v[0];
    });
    console.log(noBlankValues);
```

Comment: do you have only nested arrays with a single value, beside the sparse array? do you have `null` values to filter out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract values from an array of arrays in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083524/how-to-extract-values-from-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map array items and then filter for empty strings.

```js
var values = [[1], ["a"], , ["b"], [""], ["c"]],
    result = values
        .map(([v]) => v)
        .filter(v => v !== '');
    
console.log(result);
```

ES5

```js
var values = [[1], ["a"], , ["b"], [""], ["c"]],
    result = values
        .map(function (v) { return v[0]; })
        .filter(function (v) { return v !== ''; });
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you. For some reason google sheets api does not accept it. Do you know why?

Comment: maybe the older style works for you, without destructuring and arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and `filter` like this. The `flat` method also removes holes in arrays ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Flattening_and_array_holes))

```js
const values = [[1],["a"],,["b"],[""],["c"]];
const noBlankValues = values.flat().filter(a => a);
console.log(noBlankValues);
```

The above filter removes all the [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values. If you specifically want to remove null and empty strings:

```js
const values = [[1],["a"],,["b"],[""],["c"]];
const noBlankValues = values.flat().filter(a => a !== null && a !== "");
console.log(noBlankValues);
```

Note: [Browser compatibility for `flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: It should probably be noted that `flat` is currently in Stage 3 and therefore [has limited support across browsers](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#test-Array.prototype.{flat,_flatMap})

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that, filter function requires a boolean return [MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Syntax)

This will filter the values first, giving you the array of no blanks.

```js
values = [[1],["a"],,["b"],[""],["c"]];
noBlankValues = values.filter(function (el) {
  return el[0] != null && el[0] != "";
});

console.log(noBlankValues);
```

You can the loop through the array using the map function to get the items directly in the main array.

```js
values = [[1],["a"],,["b"],[""],["c"]];
noBlankValues = values.filter(function (el) {
  return el[0] != null && el[0] != "";
}).map(function(item) {
  return item[0];
});

console.log(noBlankValues);
```