# Javascript - How to flatten just first position value of array inside an array?

Tags: javascript

The variable i have:

```
var array = [['test1', 0], ['test2', 3], ['test4', 45]]
```

So i need some type of flatten but just for the first values of every array, the output should be:

```
['test1', 'test2', 'test4']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: A simple `for` loop would be enough. Or `.map()`, or `.reduce()`, ...

Comment: [How to extract values from an array of arrays in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083524/how-to-extract-values-from-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+get+first+column+of+array) of [Get column from a two dimensional array](/q/7848004/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

Try using Array.map
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
var array = [['test1', 0], ['test2', 3], ['test4', 45]] 

var arrayMapd = array.map(item => item[0])
```